# Azure Bing API Code Java SLOW

Tags: java, search, azure, odata, bing-api

I’m trying out the Azure Bing Search API (for url links only) and was wondering if someone could help refine my java so that it doesn’t take 1.5 to 2.5 seconds to get the API return.

I think I’ve found the bottleneck, but not sure how to remedy it.

Specifically, after offering my search term and accountKey, I set up a URLConnection. Up to this point the application runs – and quickly – however I don’t get anything back. For that I then create an InputStream and run a while loop to add all characters to a StringBuilder. This is the part that significantly degrades the speed.

Is there a faster way to get the search results than what I’m doing? I haven’t tried pulling in with json nor Bing’s option to get results in a tarball but not sure that these would significantly change this.

Details – OS (I’ve tried on a basic CentOS box and Windows 7 box – both using the console in eclipse to see results). Myspeedtest.net shows 12Mbps down and 1Mbps up.

```
public static void api(String st) throws IOException{
        String bingUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27"+st+"%27";

        String accountKey = "ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF=";
        byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
        String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);

        URL url = new URL(bingUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);     
        //FROM HERE DOWN IS WHAT SEEMS TO TAKE FOREVER. 
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        int numCharsRead;
        char[] charArray = new char[1024];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
            sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

EDIT #### EDIT ### EDIT ##### EDIT

I just tried another way of doing this with json and the Apache httpclient. Again, this works great too, but **slow**. Maybe its Msft's service?

```
package com.search;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class BingAPI2 {
public static void getBing() throws Exception {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            String accountKey = "ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF=";
            byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
            String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27Datamarket%27&$top=10&$format=Json");
            httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic <"+accountKeyEnc+">");

            System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

            // Create a response handler
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(responseBody);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try making the request from a browser?

Comment: I mean type this into your browser: https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27Datamarket%27&$top=10&$format=Json

Comment: Yes, now that is fast! Unfortunately, I need to do this programatically where I bring the Url's in as variables (Java). If I use just your URL above in a java json parser (Jackson or whatever) Bing sends me a 401 error.